# list sort sencha by number

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm using sencha touch and having problems with sorting a Ext.list by number via sortes.

To be more specific:

code:

```
mydata=[

    {id:'1', name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Iban Gavirol, TLV  ",long:"33.20",lati:"31.20",distance:"1"},
    {id:"2", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Roteshild, TLV  ",long:"34.79",lati:"32.06",distance:"23"},
    {id:"3", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Dizingoff, TLV  ",long:"34.80",lati:"32.07",distance:"44"},
    {id:"4", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Hanamal, TLV  ",long:"30.10",lati:"30.01",distance:"55"},
    {id:"5", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Shenkar, Herzelia  ",long:"33.20",lati:"29.20",distance:"66"},
    {id:"6", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Oshiskin, Ramat Hasharon  ",long:"30.20",lati:"29.20",distance:"4"},
    {id:"7", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Waizman, Kfar Sava  ",long:"33.20",lati:"31.20",distance:"44"},
    {id:"8", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Hatayasim, Ramat Gan  ",long:"33.20",lati:"31.20",distance:"3"},
    {id:"9", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Herzel, Be'er Sheva  ",long:"33.20",lati:"31.20",distance:"54"},
    {id:"10", name:"Toni Vespa " , address:"Hashunit, Eilat  ",long:"33.20",lati:"31.20",distance:"53"}
    ];

Ext.regModel('Stores', {
    fields: [{name:'id',type:'string'} , {name:'name',type:'string'} , {name:'address',type:'string'} ,{name:'long',type:'number'} , {name:'lati',type:'number'},{name:'distance',type:'number'}]
});


 var ListStore= new Ext.data.Store({
    model:'Stores',
    /*sorters: 'distance',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('distance');
    },*/    

});
```

I'm trying to sort the distance record by size.

I'll be pleased for any help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because you're setting distance as a string, try just setting it as an integer (remove the surrounding quotes)

Comment: Thanks for response,
Tried that, it didn't work for me...
actually I succeeded to do that with string but it sort just by the first character...

Comment: Did you try type int instead of number?

Comment: Also for your grouping, are you going to have many items with distance: 33? You can round to the nearest 10, or whatever grouping logic you want to do...

Comment: TIP: if you want to sort a list after you updated the list try:
ListStore.sort('recored name','ASC');

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I added

var ListStore= new Ext.data.Store({
    model:'Stores',
    sorters: 'distance',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('distance');
    },

});
TIP: if you want to sort a list after you updated the list try:
ListStore.sort('recored name','ASC');